# where is the `IPython` builtin magics and extensions defined

Tags: ipython

I wanted to see how magics are defined from some sample source but did not find info from web.

Moreover, where should the `IPython` extensions reside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand how to deploy your custom magic you need to read 2 sectinos of IPython's documentation:

- [How to write your own magic](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/custommagics.html)
- [How to write an extension](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/index.html)

Then you will see that generally a magic is simply a class that define magics methods in Python module.

[Here](https://github.com/Carreau/cffi_magic) is for example a self contained IPython magic as an extension, the code is not the best, but just to show you it can be small.

As to where the IPython's builtin's one are defined, they all are in [this folder](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/tree/master/IPython/core/magics), though I would not recommend to take them as an example, as there is a lot of historical baggage and can be quite complex.

A more recent [full example](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/10750/files) and will appear in the docs once next version of IPython is released.

Comment: thank you @Matt. I found the folder you pointed to. But there I cannot find the definition for `autoreload`. Isn't it a builtin magic?

Comment: It's in IPython/extensions/autoreload.py